# jqGrid: PHP 8+ Breaking Demos and code based on Demos

Tags: php, jqgrid

I recently upgraded to PHP 8.09 and noticed my jqGrids were not working. They worked on all previous versions of PHP. After some investigation, I found that the demo code uses a PHP class object **$responce** which does not exist or has not been instantiated. the code fails with "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "page" on null "

The code is based on the trirand server demo code code for loading JSON data from a MySQL server.

Please see "A number of warnings have been converted into Error exceptions" at https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php

Attempting to write to a property of a non-object. Previously this implicitly created an stdClass object for null, false and empty strings.
Attempting to access unqualified constants which are undefined. Previously, unqualified constant accesses resulted in a warning and were interpreted as strings.

All of this means the jqGrid demo code on trirand will fail using PHP 8+. There doesn't appear to be a php.ini setting to turn these exceptions off. Please let me know what the best approach would be to work around this problem. If you could provide some code using $responce as an array that would help.

Thanks

**Update:**

To get around the problem, I have created an example, that sets the $responce object as an array variable.

**jqGrid Server Side PHP with MySQL**

```
...
$page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page
$limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
$sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;
// connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword)
or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error conecting to db.");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM invheader a, clients b WHERE a.client_id=b.client_id");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$count = $row['count'];

if( $count >0 ) {
    $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
} else {
    $total_pages = 0;
}
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
$SQL = "SELECT a.id, a.invdate, b.name, a.amount,a.tax,a.total,a.note FROM invheader a, clients b WHERE a.client_id=b.client_id ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());
$responce=array();
$responce['page'] = $page;
$responce['total'] = $total_pages;
$responce['records'] = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $responce['rows'][$i]['id']=$row['id']; 
    $responce['rows'][$i]['cell']=array($row['id'],date('m/d/Y',strtotime($row['invdate'])),$row['name'],$row['amount'],$row['tax'],$row['total'],$row['note']);
    $i++;
}        
echo json_encode($responce);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked the demo, but it seems the solution is to initiate the variable.

In order to solve the problem, add in your code (somewhere at the beginning and before assign any property -> value to $response object)

```
$response = new stdClass();
...
```

I will check the demo and if there is something special will replay to this post
Regards

Comment: HI,
Please see the 2nd PHP 8+ backward Incompatibility "Attempting to access unqualified constants which are undefined." As written, the demos will fail even if you instantiate the variable with $responce = new stdClass(); You would have to create a PHP class and include with all properties defined in the constructor. This is why I suggested changing $responce to an array example.

Thanks